# skipping incompatible xxx.a when searching for -l

Tags: clang, filenames

When compiling my project I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../../Build/qtpropertybrowser/Linux/Develop/libqtpropertybrowser.a when searching for -lqtpropertybrowser
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lqtpropertybrowser
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../../Build/libqxt/Linux/Develop/libqxt.a when searching for -lqxt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lqxt
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I assume that if anything, the files it should be searching for should be qtpropertybrowser and qxt. Is this correct? And if so, how do I change this?

New to Linux by the way.

Comment: Chances are you're building on a 64 bit system and those are 32 bit libraries (or vice-versa). The file names are correct, it is the contents that the linker is complaining about. Are you building the libraries or the main source files with the -m32 option?

Comment: I reinstalled Linux, 32-bit this time. And everything seems to work like a charm! Thank you.